# Java Syncronization on two objects results in dead lock

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, reentrantlock

I need to implement some basic money transfer logic between accounts.
For the transfer being consistent, I take advantage of syncronization lock.

This is Account object:

```
class Account {
    UUID id;
    double balance;
}
```

This is inside transfer worker class:

```
    public void transfer(Account source, Account target) throws InterruptedException {
        Object firstLock = target.id.compareTo(source.id)  > 0 ? target : source;
        Object secondLock = target.id.compareTo(source.id)  < 0 ? target : source;
        synchronized (firstLock) {
            synchronized (secondLock) {
                // Money tranfer logic
            }   
        }
    }
```

My question is if source accunt doesn't have enough funds I'm planning to wait that thread until it got funds from other operations. For this one I have waited() for source account. But it ended up with deadlock because target account locks is still on my threds. how can I achive that one ? Can you show me proper way to accomplish this problem ?

This is what I'm trying to postpone money transfer for source accounts which doesn't have

```
    public void transfer(Account source, Account target) throws InterruptedException {
        Object firstLock = target.id.compareTo(source.id)  > 0 ? target : source;
        Object secondLock = target.id.compareTo(source.id)  < 0 ? target : source;
        synchronized (firstLock) {
            synchronized (secondLock) {
                while(source.balance <= 0 ) {
                    source.wait();
                }
                
                // Money tranfer logic
                
                source.notifyAll();
            }   
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Never compare the result of `compareTo` to anything other than 0. The only guarantees on its result are less than zero, zero, or greater than zero.

Comment: Also, your conditions are not complementary: `<` is not the complement of `>`.

Comment: just saw it, it should be 0, my mistake,

Comment: Also expression to determine firstLock is wrong. It compares t's ID to itself.

Comment: It is really a strange code, I don't think it works if you change `1` to `0`

Comment: where did you initialize `s` and `t`?

Comment: Suppose that it's coming for somewhere else, for simplicity I have added null.

Comment: @HilmiYamcı you could declare them as method parameters instead.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for locking mechanism ? @AndyTurner

Comment: sorry I'm correcting it right now @AndyTurner

Comment: `wait()` only releases the lock of the object the method was invoked on. So it will wait while still holding the target’s lock. This can lead to a deadlock. But even when this doesn’t cause a deadlock, there’s the problem that you’re invoking `source.notifyAll()` where you actually need `target.notifyAll()`, as only transferring money *to* an account can raise it above zero (which is the condition other threads may be waiting for).